# How to control the scroll behaviour when there is a long event attached to it

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

I have a div with a scroll event on it. The scroll event is a sync function that takes some time to be computed. I see that the navigators might react to this situation with 2 different behaviours.

1- The scroll is freezed until the scroll event ends and then it will trigger the next scroll event.

2- I can scroll fluidly, but the scroll event is triggered once the previous event is done.

I would like to know how can I control and decide which one of the two scenarios the user will face.

codepen: https://codepen.io/xmorelll/pen/wvdmbYq

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");
const text = document.getElementById("text");



container.addEventListener('scroll', (event) => {
  //sleep 1Second to simulate that the program is busy.
  let a = new Date().getTime();
  while(new Date().getTime() < a + 1000){};
  
  text.style.top = container.scrollTop + "px"; 
});
```

```css
#container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  overflow: auto;
}

#content {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
  position: relative;
}

#text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    <span id="text">Hola</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the scroll? Load from a backend service?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do in the scroller. Freezing the scroll is definitely not a good idea but again, what's the sync action you got that's time-consuming?

Comment: No, nothing from the server. the scroll event function is sync as I said. In my real situation I am doing an infinite scroll table that is rendering the new rows in real time while scrolling, and removing the ones left outside the screen.  But my question is how can I decide between each situation. Because so far, for the same code, in some PC the scroll is freezed and in other PC the scroll is fluid.

Comment: @XavierMorellLlorens It might be approppriate to include your code for inifinite scroll table in your codepen

Comment: Adding my infinite-scroll code will be the same than changing the: while(new Date().getTime() < a + 1000){};   For a lot of code in my codepen. Don't see why it will be helpful. My question is how to make that this scroll event in this codepen does not freeze the scroll in any situation.